# How to combine multiple collections into single collection in Laravel 5.x?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.3

I am using Laravel 5.3 with mariaDB 10.1.x.

I have several SQL queries which will be used for one report table. I would like to use multiple queries (each query is not that simple at all), rather than one complex single query for maintenance purpose.

what I want to do is to get results from each queries to collection format and combine these with single collection like the collection from one big queries.

(1) collection from first query

```
$a = DB::table('first_name')->where(...)->join(...)->leftJoin(...)->get();

result
-----------------------
primary_key  first_name
    1           John
    2           Mary 
-----------------------
```

(2) collection from second query.

```
$b = DB::table('last_name')->where(...)->join(...)->leftJoin(...)->get();

Result
-----------------------
primary_key  last_name
    1           Doe
    2           Jane 
-----------------------
```

(3) collection that I want ( combine (1) + (2) using primary_key )

```
-----------------------------------
primary_key  first_name  last_name
    1           John        Doe
    2           Mary        Jane 
-----------------------------------
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

How about this? Not sure if this is the best method though:

```
$keyedA = $a->keyBy('primary_key')->all();
$keyedB = $b->keyBy('primary_key')->all();
$combined = array_merge_recursive($keyedA, $keyedB);
```

I don't see any helper methods do the key merges though, not sure if I have read it correctly

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I don't think I fully explain the situation in detail but  A have all the primary Keys but B doesn't always have all the keys, it can possibly have missing keys ( means missing rows in compare with A) 
For example, primary keys for A is 1,2,3 in other hand Primary keys for B is 1,2 only.
So it means B should work like 'Left Outer Join' in SQL.